# How to use 100% height with css

Tags: html, css

Attempt #3.

Using css, **with a strict doctype**, can someone please draw 4 div boxes to meet these requirements.

1. The wrapper or outermost div will scale in height. That means that it could be any height.
2. The middle div should **always** be 100% high to match the outer/parent div (#1 in my list)
3. The next div should be positioned **inside**, and at the **top** of div #2
4. The last div should be positioned **inside**, and at the **bottom** of div #2

NOTES:
If you use absolute positioning for this, you will put divs 3 and 4 outside of div #1 and that won't work. The key is to keep divs 3 and 4 **within** div #2

Comment: Maybe you should open a http://www.jsFiddle.net to better explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: No, this is my 3rd attempt at trying to get this to work. I've wasted 2 entire days trying to get this working. I want to make the requirements crystal clear so I don't have a dog and pony show going on like I did the last two times I tried this.

Comment: See what I mean, Alex? Steve already doesn't understand it.

Comment: @Steve, I think the requirements are very clear. What exactly is it that you are having a hard time understanding?

Comment: Define #1 more clearly. What should the outermost `div` be scaling to? The contents inside #2? A predefined `height` set in the CSS? The height of the user's browser? Or something else entirely different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="middle">
  <div id="top">top</div>
  <div id="bottom">bottom</div>
 </div>
</div>

#wrapper { height: 200px;  position: relative;  }
#middle { height: 100%;  }
#bottom { position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
```

It should work for any height you give the #wrapper.

you can play with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/dmBsa/

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thanks for helping me out again. I got so frustrated this morning that I just gave up. I can't believe that this is turned out to be so difficult.

Comment: holy sh*t! i was like "i know i 've seen this question before..." so - decided to give divs a try, heh? going to sleep very soon, but if you ain't got it, i can check again tomorrow.

Comment: hahaha.. Yep, it's me bro! :) And I've tried it and it seems to work just fine. I'm not sure why the absolute positioning doesn't push the content outside div #1 but it looks good.

Comment: Sebastian, thanks for all of your help, especially this morning. I'll play with this and if I have any issues, I'll post back here tomorrow.